# Send text from keyboard android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

i am currently developing an keyboard app and i would like to know how i am able to send the text directly instead of it just appearing inside the edittext of application like Whatsapp or text messaging.

Comment: What you mean by "text directly" ??

Comment: for example. i have a key button "k" . i would like to tap on it and it will automatically send "k" to whatsapp chat directly @RemeesMSyde

Comment: You want your keyboard to send data to an app other than the one the user is looking at?  I see that feature as being more likely to cause problems than help anything, if not be outright malware.